# Dependencia circular en clases ES6 usando Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, clase, dependencias

¡Hola!

Tengo un problema de dependencia circular en un proyecto de Angular (4.3.X).

En el directorio `app/models` se encuentran varios archivos que representan los modelos recibidos por la API.

*Caso de ejemplo:*

```
// center.ts
import {User} from './user';

export class Center {
  name: string;
  users: User[];

  constructor(data: any = {}) {
    this.name = data.name;
    this.users = (data.users || []).map(user => new User(user));
  }
}


// user.ts
import {Center} from './center';

export class User {
  name: string;
  center: Center | null;

  constructor(data: any = {}) {
    this.name = data.name;
    this.center = data.center ? new Center(data.center) : null;
  }
}
```

Obviamente, esto produce una dependencia circular.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi solución ha sido relacionar los modelos en el servicio y no en el constructor de cada modelo.
Por lo que los modelos quedarían así:

```
// center.ts
import {User} from './user';

export class Center {
  name: string;
  users: User[] = [];

  constructor(data: any = {}) {
    this.name = data.name;
  }
}


// user.ts
import {Center} from './center';

export class User {
  name: string;
  center: Center | null = null;

  constructor(data: any = {}) {
    this.name = data.name;
  }
}
```

Y el servicio de `User` de esta forma:

```
// user.service.ts
// [...]
export class UserService {
  // [...]
  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
   this.http.get('/users/end/point')
     .map(body => body.json())
     .map(usersData => usersData.map(userData => {
       return createInstance(userData);
     });
  }
}

function createInstance(data: any): User {
  if (!data) { return null; }

  const user = new User(data);

  if (data.center) {
    // Esto no crea una dependencia circular
    user.center = new Center(data.center);
  }

  return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

en realidad no es tan complicado. Lo que pasa es que en algun servicio estas llamando el modelo y en el componente tambien. Borra el llamado del modelo en el servicio y listo, se soluciona.